# changing background-colour in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, boilerplate

just a quickie...i am trying to change the colour of certain backgrounds within bootstrap.
i have removed the main background colour from the bootstrap css. So i am able to add my own. i have created a div with content and i want that background to be a different colour to the rest of the page. so assigning the background color to that div.

but its still white, even though i have removed the default background colour from the bootstrap

this is now the default body css for bootstrap

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333333;
}
```

any ideas?

here is an an example of what I'm trying to say. even though i have added a id its not showing up

[image]

Think i have found the issue, but have no idea how or why they are here....most of my style sheets are in the 'other' folder??? any ideas why or how this happened?
[image]

Comment: Protip: Use Chrome or Firefox's element inspector to see where divs are getting their styles from, or why they're not getting it

Comment: You don't need to remove the main background color. CSS is cascading, i.e. later style definitions override earlier ones. The problem must be somewhere else. What style definition do you use to set the background of your divs?

Comment: for example this. #site-footer{
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
}

Comment: just looked in chrome, and the id or classes i make dont seem to even be listed

Comment: You have a link? And if your CSS isn't showing try hitting CTRL + F5 a few times to hard refresh the cache.

Comment: afraid i dont have a link Rick as working off a mamp. Its like the id / class i have assigned it...doesnt exsist. even though its in the index and css files

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that main.css is being loaded? Is it listed in Chrome's Resources tab? If it is, is the latest footer definition in there? Your screenshot suggests that none of the footer properties are being applied, not just the BG colour.

Since the inspector screenshot references a copy of bootstrap.css that's on your production server I'm wondering if you're also loading [this copy](http://iampaulb.com/css/main.css) of your main.css file.

Comment: included another photo for you :)

Comment: Can you post more of your markup, particularly the code that you're using to load your CSS and JS files? For one thing it looks as though everything's being loaded twice. Then there's the fact they're all categorised as 'other', which suggests that the browser can't figure out what kind of files they are for some reason. If you copy one of your link `href` values and attempt to load the file itself, does it display correctly?

Comment: I dont on me. But i have been using windows and mac, sublime and coda, and dropbox and github to keep all everything in sync! Could this of played around with the files? As i was editing a live site and that worked? its all very confusing

Comment: Without further info it's impossible to know what's going on. Can you post your code on [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?